# Pandas - Summing previous 6 months and next 6 months

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time, cumulative-sum

I have a dataset with sales per customer, per month. I have both a date field (e.g. June 2018) and a "month counter" which gives each month a progressive number (e.g., if data starts in Jan 2018, Jan 2018 is "1", Dec 2018 is "12", and Jan 2019 is "13").
Please see the image, the first 4 columns is a sample of the data I have.

I'd like, for each month and each customer, to sum the sales of the previous 6 months and of the next 6 months, like in the last 2 columns in the attached image.
For instance: for month 1 and customer "John", I'd like to sum sales for month 2,3,4,5,6,7, only looking at "John", this would be "Next 6 months sales" for John in month 1. Reverse logic for the last 6 months sales.

I tried building a for loop and building some functions, but I didn't quite manage to build anything like what I need.

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSq4c.png)

Comment: Use `groupby` then `rolling`. Please put your data as _text_ and not as an image.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.